# extract second row values in spark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have spark dataframe for table (1000000x4) sorted by second column
I need to get 2 values second row, column 0 and second row, column 3
How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need the values it's pretty simple, just use the `DataFrame`'s internal `RDD`. You didn't specify the language, so I will take this freedom to show you how to achieve this using `python2`.

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("Bonsanto", 20, 2000.00), 
                                 ("Hayek", 60, 3000.00), 
                                 ("Mises", 60, 1000.0)], 
                                ["name", "age", "balance"])
requiredRows = [0, 2]
data = (df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
        .filter(lambda ((name, age, balance), index): index in requiredRows)
        .collect())
```

And now you can manipulate the variables inside the data list. By the way, I didn't remove the index inside every `tuple` just to provide you another idea about how this works.

```py
print data

#[(Row(name=u'Bonsanto', age=20, balance=2000.0), 0),
# (Row(name=u'Mises', age=60, balance=1000.0), 2)]
```

Comment: For small `n` `orderBy(...).limit(n)`  would be better, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: or `.head(n)(n-1)` if you want to pop the row out of the rdd/dataset/DataFrame